# mongomock - preserve mock mongodb collections across unit tests with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pytest, pymongo-3.x, mongomock

I am using `mongomock` to mock MongoDB collections in unit tests, which are built around `pytest`. I usually have to create a mock database and collection and then perform the assertions for every single test like this:

```
import mongomock
import pymongo

@mongomock.patch(servers=(("server.com", 27017),))
def test_func1():
   # create mock collection
   docs = [{"Name": John}, {"Name": "Jack"}]
   mock_client = pymongo.MongoClient("server.com")
   mock_client.db.collection.insert_many(docs)
   
   # perform assertions as required for func1

@mongomock.patch(servers=(("server.com", 27017),))
def test_func2():
   # create mock collection
   docs = [{"Name": John}, {"Name": "Jack"}]
   mock_client = pymongo.MongoClient("server.com")
   mock_client.db.collection.insert_many(docs)

   # perform assertions as required for func2
```

The above works fine, but I would like to have to avoid creating a mock database for every unit test. I have tried to create an helper function that creates the mock database and returns the mock client, but when I call that function within an unit test, the mock databases do not persist. How can I make the mock database to persist across tests?

Comment: You might want to take a look at how [scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) works in pytest and make use of fixtures. You are probably looking for a module or a session scope. Make sure you also pay attention to ensuring your tests remain deterministic by sharing this state across tests.